# Only one event is realised

Tags: probability

Let's say I have $n$ events $A_i$

How can I write using $\cup, \cap, \overline{A}$, the fact that only one event is realised.

What I've done so far is :

for $n = 1$ we have the formula : $A_1$

for $n = 2$, we have the formula : $\overline{A_1} \cup \overline{A_2}$.

for $n = 3$, it's already harder for me to find the answer, I drew a Venn diagram but it doesn't help.

It's seems like the general formula is something like :

$$\overline{\bigcup_{i = 1}^{2^n} \bigcap_{j \in (I \in \mathcal{P}([\![1, n]\!]))} A_j }$$

Like that I get rid of all the intersection, but maybe there is something simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $\bigcup \limits _i {A_i}$ is the even that one (at least) of the $A_i$ occurs and that $\bigcup \limits _{i \neq j} A_i \cap A_j$ the event that two (or more) of the $A_i$ occurs.

Then the event "one and only one of the $A_i$ occurs", is $$\bigcup \limits _i {A_i} - \bigcup \limits _{i \neq j} A_i \cap A_j = \bigcup \limits _i {A_i} \cap \overline {\bigcup \limits _{i \neq j} A_i \cap A_j} = \bigcup \limits _i {A_i} \cap {\bigcap \limits _{i \neq j} \overline {A_i} \cup \overline {A_j}}$$

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some misunderstanding. For example, for the case where $n=2$, $\overline{A_1} \cup \overline{A_2}$ might imply that both $A_1$ and $A_2$ are not realized, since your expression means that *at least* one of the two events is not realized, but might also imply that both events are not realized. I would write the general case as follows. The event that exactly one event of $n$ events $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ is realized is given by $$\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^nA_k\right)\bigcap_{\substack{i,j=1\\i\neq j}}^n\overline{A_i\cap A_j}.$$
Now the first union says that there is at least one event realized and the intersection tells that there cannot be realized more then one event.